# Const Object, Const Member Function and Mutable Variable in C++

Tags: c++, function, constants, mutable, member-functions

I know that a `const` object can't call a non-`const` member function. It says so in the C++14 Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2014) Section 9.3.2, Paragraph 3:

> A *cv-qualified* member function can be called on an object-expression (5.2.5) only if the object-expression is as cv-qualified or less-cv-qualified than the member function.

Does this constraint make sense if the member function does not modify anything? Or if the member function modifies a mutable variable? For example:

```
class My_Class {
    public:
        mutable int value;
        void function( int x ) const { value = x; } //     Correct
      //void function( int x )       { value = x; } // Not Correct
        My_Class() : value(0) {}
};

int main(){

    const My_Class obj;
    obj.function( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

In this specific case, if the function is `const`, the program is correct and the function can modify a variable of the `const` object. If the function is not `const`, the program is not correct. So in the end, I need to write `const` to be able to modify something, which should be the opposite purpose of `const`.

Does anyone know why this rule is designed this way?

Comment: `const` objects are not meant to be changed. That's that. `mutable` is just a cheat and is meant to be used on member variables which aren't really part of the internal state of the object (e.g. a mutex, which must be locked or unlocked regardless of `const`).

Comment: re. "If the function is not const, the program is not correct"... const is used to indicate conceptual sameness not byte sameness. non-const functions are not expected to have to change something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does [Section 9.3.2, Paragraph 3 of] make sense if the member function does not modify anything? Or if the member function modifies a mutable variable?

Yes, it does. The caller of the function cannot in general know whether the function modifies any non mutable member. It knows whether the function is const or not, so the compiler can only make a decision based on that.

A non const function **could** modify the non mutable state, so you obviously may not call it on a const object. Whether the non const function does modify the state is irrelevant since it is an implementation detail that is not available when deciding if the call is allowed. In other words, constness is part of the interface of the function, while the implementation of the function is not part of the interface. The interface of the function is fully specified by its declaration.

An example:

```
struct C {
    mutable int a;
            int b;
    void do_something();
};

const C c;
c.do_something();
```

Does it make sense to allow the call `do_something`? Does the fact that `do_something` might not modify `b` affect that? How could we assume that `do_something` does not modify `b`?

The answers are: It wouldn't make sense. It does not have an effect. There is no way we could make such assumption.

Writing a non const member function that doesn't modify any non mutable state - at least potentially or allow such modification indirectly by returning a non const reference / pointer to `this` - makes little sense, although the standard does permit doing so.

> So in the end, I need to write const to be able to modify something, which should be the opposite purpose of const.

That might seem oxymoronic, but that is because it  is an oversimplification. You need to write const to be able to modify **the mutable state of a const object**. The const that you write declares that you do not modify any non mutable state, and that declaration gives the permission to call it on const objects.

Your commented-out non-const function is still correct to use with non-const objects.

Comment: No the constraint is not sensible, and doesn't exist!  The OP seems to think that a non-const function *cannot* modify a mutable member.  This is nonsense of course.

Comment: Re-reading the question:  The constraint in the standard makes perfect sense of course.  The problem is what the OP is reading into it.

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm not quite sure if OP thinks that. I can see that they have trouble distinguishing the separation between the interface of the function from how the function is implemented. I clarified what sensibility I'm referring to.

Comment: I know a non-`const` function can modify a mutable member. I wrote `// Not Correct` because it was called by a `const` object. I also know about the use of mutable keyword, just tried to make the example simple. The explanation about function interface is clarifying. Thanks to both @user2079303 and @MartinBonner for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding in your question:

```
class My_Class {
    public:
        mutable int value;
        void function( int x )       { value = x; } // Absolutely fine
        My_Class() : value(0) {}
};
```

`mutable` does not mean "can only be modified in a `const` member function".  It means "can be modified *even* in a  `const` member function".

Comment: I know your code is fine with a non-`const` object. However, in my example the object is `const` intentionally.  So the non-`const` function is not fine if it is called by a `const` object (like in my example). To the best of my knowledge, that is not correct.

Comment: @JL:  You said:  "So in the end, I need to write const to be able to modify something ..." : No! There is no need to write const to be able to modify something.  `mutable` says  "you can modify *this* bit, even if the enclosing object is mutable.

Comment: I understand your point, and I already knew about mutable. However, the sentence "So in the end, I need to write const to be able to modify something ..." remains true in my opinion. If I don't use `const`, the program does not compile, because it is not correct according to the Standard. If I use `const`, it compiles and I can modify the variable. As @user2079303 said, it is an oversimplification, but in a practical sense for this specific case, that's what is happening. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) keyword,

> Applies to non-static class members of non-reference non-const type and specifies that the member does not affect the externally visible state of the class (as often used for mutexes, memo caches, lazy evaluation, and access instrumentation). mutable members of const class instances are modifiable

You're questioning the validity of a C++ keyword. I feel the examples in this definition, provide positive proof that such a keyword is needed, and that `mutable` as imagined by the designers of the language is a boon to us.